# PyCharm - Git Issue

Tags: git, pycharm

I have installed GIT locally. In PyCharm, I am trying update project (Merge or Rebase) and receiving the error message:

> Can't update: no tracked branch ; No tracked branch configured for branch master ; 
>   To make your branch track a remote branch call, for example, git branch --set-upstream master origin/master

Could you help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your current branch does not track anything on the remote. You need to configure tracking using the suggested command - e.g. to set local master track the origin/master call `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`

IDE could help with this, but it is not implemented yet - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128375

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to run the commands: git status -> On branch master, nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: git branch --set-upstream-to master origin/master
fatal: branch 'origin/master' does not exist

Comment: Do you have a remote configured for the repo? Is the master branch present on the remote? The error means there is no reference in the local repo that points to remote master at origin. `git fetch` should solve this if the remote is configured